# Variable value passed from page to another page stays the same

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, variables

What i am trying to do is to pass a value, using a variable,  from one page using php to another page using php and then pass this value in the second page from php to javascript.

I initialize the variable in HTML depending on which image i click.
The problem is that every time i pass a different value(different values are 12 and 7 in the code below), meaning that i clicked on a different image,and after reloading my page, i still get the first value.

I tried unsetting the variable and/or session_destroy() but with no luck. To be more clear:

First page:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="secondpage.php"><img src="images/first_image.png" alt="image" <?php $_SESSION['choice'] = 12; ?>></a>
    <a href="secondpage.php"><img src="images/second_image.png" alt="image" <?php $_SESSION['choice'] = 7; ?>></a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Second page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$option = $_SESSION['choice'];
//unset($_SESSION['choice']); //failed
echo $option;                 //option is always 12
//session_destroy();         //failed

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Monuments</title>

<script>
var option = <?php echo json_encode($option); ?>;
//var option = "<?php echo $option; ?>";      // i tried also this way 
alert("option is : " + option);  //option is always 12
</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me what is the problem?
Or recommend any better solutions for what i want to do?

Comment: choice always 7 or 12?, u purely assigning value to choice...u need to use js/ajax to achive what u want cause u expecting choice to be change on certain link..use $GET instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning values to `$_SESSION['choice']` in your `HTML`.

Using `sessions` is not really the proper way to do what you are trying to achieve.

On your first page, use a `$_GET` parameter to identify the selected monument.

```
<a href="secondpage.php?choice=12"><img src="images/first_image.png" alt="image"></a>
```

On your second page, you can get this parameter by using `$_GET['choice']`

The code with the changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="secondpage.php?choice=12"><img src="images/first_image.png" alt="image"></a>
    <a href="secondpage.php?choice=7"><img src="images/second_image.png" alt="image"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

And the second page:

```
<?php
$option = $_GET['choice'];
echo $option;
?>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Monuments</title>

    <script>
    var option = <?php echo $option; ?>;
    alert("option is: " + option);
    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, i know that. that means i do not need to use the variable $option? I'm not sure if i completely understand what is my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You are actually setting the value of the SESSION variable twice in these lines of code. First, you set it to 12, and then you set it to 7. $_SESSION['choice'] cannot have two values at the same time. When you say "I initialize the variable in HTML depending on which image i click." this is incorrect. Both lines of code run regardless of what the user does, since PHP runs all the code before outputting the page.

```
<a href="secondpage.php"><img src="images/first_image.png" alt="image" <?php $_SESSION['choice'] = 12; ?>></a>
<a href="secondpage.php"><img src="images/second_image.png" alt="image" <?php $_SESSION['choice'] = 7; ?>></a>
```

Another approach would be to have two different hyperlinks, and set the variable on the second page.

First page:

```
<a href="secondpage.php?choice=12"><img src="images/first_image.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="secondpage.php?choice=7"><img src="images/second_image.png" alt="image"></a>
```

Second page:

```
if (isset($_GET['choice'])){
    $option = $_GET['choice'];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i didn't choose your as correct because the if(isset.. didn't work for me..

Comment: That's odd... Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: maybe i am doing something wrong again, but i had to choose between your answer and the other that i have chosen

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you seem to be missing a fundamental point about PHP. (It takes a bit of getting used to). As PHP is server script, you need to remember that all the PHP in a page is executed before any of the resulting client side code (HTML/JavaScript etc.). So your assignments to $_SESSION['choice'] will simply be executed on the server before any of the HTML is sent to the client. You need to focus on putting a form round your anchor tags and have them use javascript to assign the value 12 or 7 to a hidden field before POSTing the form data using a submit.
Either to the current page (where assigning it to the SESSION value would make sense before navigating to another page) - OR - to your destination page avoiding the need to assign to the SESSION variable.
Hope this points you in the right direction.
.. Just by way of example...

```
<?php
session_start();

if (array_key_exists('choice',$_POST))
{
  $_SESSION['choice']=$_POST['choice'];
  header('Location: secondpage.php');
}
// Assuming you have an array of images with corresponding choice values...
$images=array('12'=>'images/first_image.png','7'=>'images/second_image.png');     
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<?php
  foreach ($images as $choice=>$imagefile)
  {
?>
   <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $imagefile?>" alt="image" onclick="document.myform.choice='<?php echo $choice?>';document.myform.submit();"></a>
<?php
  }
?>
      <input type="hidden" name="choice" value="">
    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Does this make more sense?

Comment: yeah, im new to php and for i forgot about it. i will get used to it

Answer (score 0):

Why you have two variables with the same name choice?change the name of the second variable to choice2 and check the output, i believe your code is correct.

The code works

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['choice'] = 2;
 $_SESSION['choice2'] = 20;
 ?>
 <a href="sessionTest2.php">Click me</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Test2 session

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['choice'];
    echo $_SESSION['choice2'];
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```